# Pull date and us as a variable Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, date

I am trying to get certain popups to display on my app based on the date. Such as a pop up that says Happy Easter! I already have the view created. I just need to know how to pull the date and turn it into a variable so that when the date matches the date of a holiday or other event like the users birthday, the popup will display and then dismiss if double tapped, or after 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide when you want to check the date to see if it's a holiday or other special date.

One option is to subscribe to the `UIApplicationDidBecomeActive` notification. Another would be the `UIApplicationDelegate` `applicationDidBecomeActive(_:)`. IF you implement that function in your app delegate, it will get called when the app becomes active. You could then write code that checks the date, and if it is a special date, and you haven't displayed a message for that date before, display a popup on the key window.

```
//Add a var to your app delegate
var currentDate: Date?

Add a function something like this to your app delegate
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
   let newDate = Date()
   defer {
     currentDate = newDate
   }
   let calendar = Calendar.current
   guard let oldDate = currentDate else { return }
   if !calendar.isDate(oldDate, inSameDayAs: newDate) {
     //Display your popup
   }
}
```